# Would a potential Russian attack on Starlink satellite be considered an attack on NATO member?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, nato, space

Does NATO consider an attack on a satellite in space as similar to attacking the country in which the company is registered?

Comment: I'm sorry for being cynical, but I don't think this is answerable as drawing solid lines on what does and does not constitute an attack on a NATO member 1) Allows Russia to do what it wants as long as it avoids specific red lines 2) forces the hand of NATO members to a point where they must respond militarily if certain actions are taken. As far as I can see no one in NATO is interested in forcing either of these circumstances.

Comment: Just look at general at the current war in Ukraine: Russia doesn't see it as an attack, more like an operation. Words are a bit meaningless sometimes. What you probably want to know is if NATO would retaliate if a Starlink satellite would be attacked. And the answer is that nobody knows.

Comment: This sounds counterproductive. A starlink satellite is fairly cheap. Launching precision weapons into space and trying to hit something there would be pretty expensive. It would also open the pandoras box; everyone could start shooting down significantly more expensive satellites.

Comment: Note that StarLink satellites are private property. An action taken against the private property of a "citizen of a NATO member nation" is not the same thing as an action taken against the NATO member nation itself

Comment: @StianYttervik A kinetic attack on a satellite could be considered expensive. Laser attacks are pretty cheap and can be expended on a large number of targets.

Comment: @K.AlanBates True, but there is an agreement in place that space is supposed to be demilitarized. Once that is broken, it is broken for everyone.

Comment: @doneal24 AFAIK they usually only disable or temporarily disrupt them with satellites? Sure, imaging satellites can have their sensors fried, but these arent imaging satellites, or have I missed something?

Comment: To answer the question in the title: No, a **potential** Russian attack surely wouldn't, and as we currently see, isn't. An **actual** attack, otoh, might be though. ;-)

Comment: The question in the body "attack on a satellite in space" and the title "Starlink" don't match.  An attack on a commercial comms satellite (e.g. Starlink) coudl be seen very differently to an attack on a US-government (military/intel) satellite. Longer term, Starlink is meant to use many satellites, and the loss of one shouldn't have wide-ranging effects

Comment: To have noticeable effect on StarLink, Russia would need to destroy _a lot_ of them: right now, there are almost 2000 StarLink satellites in orbit. Destroying a few dozen would create a serious space debris problem that would affect Russian space missions as well (see also [Kessler Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kessler_syndrome)).

Comment: @DarkDust the debris field would affect China's space station which is near the same altitude as StarLink, they already complain about how close StarLink has gotten to their station.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This decision would be made at the time by the North Atlantic Council. In the [joint communiqué](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/news_185000.htm) issued after the 2021 NATO summit in Brussels, the parties agreed that an attack on assets in space could lead to an invocation of Article 5 (NATO's mutual defense article), but that this decision would be made on a case-by-case basis:

> We consider that attacks to, from, or within space present a clear challenge to the security of the Alliance, the impact of which could threaten national and Euro-Atlantic prosperity, security, and stability, and could be as harmful to modern societies as a conventional attack.  Such attacks could lead to the invocation of Article 5.  A decision as to when such attacks would lead to the invocation of Article 5 would be taken by the North Atlantic Council on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: But there is a clear, if qualitative, difference between attacks on state-owned-and-operated intelligence satellites vs. civilian satellites. Wryly, I note that the sheer size of Starlink’s constellation also might give aggressors a cop-out by saying any of Elon’s sats that got hit _were just collateral damage from an unrelated operation_. To that end, has NATO or the UN made a statement specifically on civilian vs. military/recon space materiel? Or does it come down to the nationality of the majority shareholder?

Comment: of course there is an important difference there between assets owned by nation states (so governments) and assets owned by citizens of nation states. Starlink isn't a government entity and isn't of strategic importance to the US government so I seriously doubt the US government would invoke article 5 if a few of them stopped working. Now if it were a GPS satellite being taken out, or a spysat, it'd be different.